# How to pass string variable in cut shell command

Tags: bash, shell

Assume that I have :
.sh file having these commands :

```
#!/bin/bash
GIT_BRANCH="origin/release/2.4.0"
echo $GIT_BRANCH
```

then, I want to compute new varible from the GIT_BRANCH (operation of substring) :
So,

```
RELEASE_VERSION=$( $GIT_BRANCH | cut -d "/" -f3)
echo $RELEASE_VERSION
```

But this does return message error : bad substitution

I tried many possibilities in the RELEASE_VERSION, but no result.
like
RELEASE_VERSION=$(echo $GIT_BRANCH | cut -d "/" -f3)
RELEASE_VERSION=$("$GIT_BRANCH" | cut -d "/" -f3) and this return empty results

Comment: You likely have an odd branch name. Try quotes - `echo "$GIT_BRANCH"`

Comment: `RELEASE_VERSION=$( $GIT_BRANCH | cut -d "/" -f3)` is nonsense. With your input data for GIT_BRANCH, this would try to execute a command `origin/release/2.4.0`. You should get an error message _bash: origin/release/2.4.0: No such file or directory_ from this. Since you claim to get a different error message, I'm pretty sure that you did **not** post here the sequence of commands which you actually have tried out.

Answer (score 3):

You are definitelly missing an `echo` statement. Following code works for me just fine.

```sh
GIT_BRANCH="origin/release/2.4.0"
RELEASE_VERSION=$(echo $GIT_BRANCH | cut -d "/" -f3)
echo $RELEASE_VERSION
```

Comment: how about this command : `echo ${REPO_GIT}%.*` ? in fact, I want to remove the extension from the REPO_GIT string